# Choose correct Select option from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this HTML/PHP Code that lists options in a select element.

Whats the best way to make the correct option selected based on a record from a MySQL database:

This works fine, but is there any easier way to do it with one line of code rather than doing an if statement per option?

```
<select name="status" id="status">
            <option value="Open"<?php if($ticket["status"]=="Open"){echo('selected="selected"');}?>>Open</option>
            <option value="Needs Action"<?php if($ticket["status"]=="Needs Action"){echo('selected="selected"');}?>>Needs Action</option>
            <option value="Customer Reply"<?php if($ticket["status"]=="Customer Reply"){echo('selected="selected"');}?>>Customer Reply</option>
            <option value="Completed"<?php if($ticket["status"]=="Completed"){echo('selected="selected"');}?>>Completed</option>
          </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an array:

```
echo "<select name='status' id='status'>";
$statuses = array('Open', 'Needs Action', 'Customer Reply', 'Completed');
foreach ($statuses as $status) {
    echo "<option value='$status' " . ($ticket['status'] == $status) ? "selected='selected'" : "" . "/>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put those values in the database or if you want to avoit it, just put them into an array and print all the options using a loop and mark as selected the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code can be shorter (and much more readable):

```
if($ticket["status"]=="Open") {
    $openSelected = "selected='selected'";
}
if($ticket["status"]=="Needs Action") {
    $needsActionSelected = "selected='selected'";
}
if($ticket["status"]=="Customer Reply") {
    $customerReplySelected = "selected='selected'";
}
if($ticket["status"]=="Completed") {
    $completedSelected = "selected='selected'";
}

<select name="status" id="status">
            <option value="Open" <?php print($openSelected) ?>>Open</option>
            <option value="Needs Action"<?php print($needsActionSelected) ?>>Needs Action</option>
            <option value="Customer Reply"<?php print($customerReplySelected) ?>>Customer Reply</option>
            <option value="Completed"<?php print($completedSelected) ?>>Completed</option>
          </select>
```

EDIT// @Barmar has a better answer.